# How can I successfully install sharetribe on windows

Tags: windows, git, github, installation

https://github.com/tlsalmin/kassi/wiki/HOW-TO-install-kassi-in-Windows-(for-Development-only) I have tried to follow all the instructions as per this link but all is in vain.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what problems you ran into (use the edit option to refine your post)

Comment: I was able to;
1. Download the necessary software
2. Successfully installed Git
3. Successfully cloned Kassi
4. Failed to Install ruby
5. Was successful with all database issues
6. Failed to install imagemagick and 
7. Failed to install sphinx